# How to apply a bevel modifier, so that it affects only specific edges?

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I am trying to apply a bevel modifier to a box with some additional buttons, however, I am struggling to apply the bevel modifier only to the top face and the edges that are connected to that face. In a nutshell, I am trying to bevel the top of the box without affecting the bottom and the buttons.

Here is an image of what I get upon applying the bevel modifier:
[image: 1]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use bevel weights, which lets you specify a value between 0 (no bevel) and 1 (full bevel).

[image]

Comment: oh yes I remember, and it's more flexible than the Vertex Group mode  ;)

Comment: Ohh yeah, this makes it so much easier, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Create a vertex group where you want the bevel to happen. In the modifier's *Limit Method* choose *Vertex Group*, and Select your vertex group.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is also a solution to this problem, one I’ve seen elsewhere before but forgot