# I have a Bevel modifier but I want some seams to be tighter than others. How can I do that?

Tags: mesh

So I'll explain my crude drawing. So I like that the bevel is doing to the outside edges but seams on the inside I want much tighter. Is there anyway to change those?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply a bevel modifier, so that it affects only specific edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179891/how-to-apply-a-bevel-modifier-so-that-it-affects-only-specific-edges) *(Shameless self promotion)*

Comment: Hello Gorgious.. Lol, I think that looks like it could work. I'll try it out!