# Is there a way to apply a weighted bevel modifier but only to selected edges

Tags: edges, bevel, vertex-groups

I know that this [How to apply a bevel modifier, so that it affects only specific edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179891/how-to-apply-a-bevel-modifier-so-that-it-affects-only-specific-edges) exists but the answers in there either talk about using vertex groups or weighted edges. And this is not always great for me.

1. **Weighted edges**:
   Sometimes I need to apply different bevel properties to different edges in the same mesh. Say, I want a part of the mesh to use different Miters or bevel amount.
2. **Vertex groups**:
   Using this, I can't seem to control weights anymore. This is going to make it near useless when fine tuning the weights become necessary. Also, sometimes, vertex groups can select the wrong edges. For eg. say that I wanted to apply the bevel on the pointed edges by selecting the 4 vertices. As you can see, that also applies the bevel on the convex edges too[image: Blender screenshot showing marked edges]

Is there a way around this?

Comment: AFAIK you can control weights with vertex groups. Each vertex is assigned to a group via a value from 0 to 1, you can manage this in either edit mode via the sidebar or using the weightpaint mode. Now the issue with bevel targeting with vertext group is that it's not edges 

Comment: @L0Lock Edges are 2 vertices and thus can be managed with vertex groups, the issue here is that the edges share a face and thus mess with the result, my answer shows a way around that.

Comment: That's what I meant...

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case i would suggest using the **vertex group method**,
 it is **non-destructive** and if not too many edges are involved should be easy to follow:

Also, using **edges** that do **not share** a face, like in the picture below,
 allows for a way to use **less bevel modifiers**.
[image: square hole in a wall with 2 diagonally opposite edges selected and circled with blue]

[image: vertex group list with 2 vertex groups with descriptive names of the two groups (topleft+bottomright) and (topright+bottomleft)]

Using the first vertex group in a bevel modifier:
[image: default bevel modifier with the before mentioned first weight map used]
You would get this:
[image: square hole in the wall, with the topleft+bottomright edge beveled in the same bevel modifier]
Doing the same once more with the other vertex group, we end up with this:
[image: hole in the wall with all four corners beveled, making it now a 8 sided hole]

All that is needed is the grouping of edges that do **NOT** share a face,
 and the usage of **vertex group** mode bevel modifiers.

[image: two bevel modifiers in vertex group limit mode, each using the default settings, but either of the vertex groups]

It's not perfect, but very powerfull and most important, **non-destructive**.

Happy blending.